# Apply class to form elements when form is disabled Angular - Ionic

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, opacity

im using Angular 9 + ionic. I have a condition that leaves my form as disabled, it works fine but the elements are very opaque and I need to decrease the opacity, for that I have a class to apply to the children elements of my form but apparently the css style is not being applied well.

My css:

```
.form-opacity-disabled .ion-label .ion-input {
   opacity: 0.8  !important;
 }
```

My HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormData"
  [class.form-opacity-disabled]="myFormData.disabled"
 (ngSubmit)="save()">

 <ion-col size="3">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label  class="label-text">Name</ion-label> 
      <ion-input formControlName="name" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
</form>
```

i tried with myFormData.disable  and "disabled" but not work

My .ts condition:

```
ngOnInit() {
  ....
  ....
  const disableForm = (localStorage.getItem('item') === '1'); //-> is true
  if(disableForm) {
      this.myFormData.disabled();
  }
}
```

How could I get the style applied to my form components?

Answer (score 1):

If the form is invalid, angular automatically add an `ng-invalid` css class to the `form` tag. This should work :

```
form.ng-invalid {
  .ion-label .ion-input {
    opacity: 0.8
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I need if or if an external condition to enable or disable. The status of the form does not serve me

Comment: for external check you should use `[ngClass]` e.g: `[ngClass]="{yourCondition != true ? 'invalidClass' : 'validClass'}"`